# Configure log4j' HTTP appender to accept self-signed certificate

Tags: java, logging, log4j, splunk

I am trying to send logs to Splunk Cloud' HTTP Event Collector using Log4J' HTTP Appender. However, it seems Splunk uses a self-signed certificate on their HTTP Event Collector, thus causing SSL Validation errors when Log4J tries to connect to it:

```
ERROR Unable to send HTTP in appender [Splunk] javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

How can I temporarily disable SSL Certificate verification (similarly to the -k option of CURL) for the HTTP Appender?

Comment: Sidebar - it's *probably* best to update your Splunk install's certs to something *not* self-signed, if you're planning on using it in this manner :)

Comment: @warren I totally agree, but it's not a self hosted version, it's a Splunk Cloud' managed instance. Therefore, I do not have control over the SSL certificate. Otherwise, it would have been fixed already.

Comment: Interesting - I was under the [apparently mistaken] impression Splunk Cloud used commercial (not self-signed) certs

Comment: @GauthierPLM Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: I did not; I made sure the whole infra uses signed certificates.